# Зависает ввод с клавиатуры при работе с библиотеками ввода с клавиатуры/мыши

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

Пытаюсь сделать `Anti-AFK` в Minecraft, суть заключается в том, чтобы при нажатии `F7` включалось `Anti-AFK` и персонаж бегал по квадрату, но так же необходимо, чтобы ввод с клавиатуры не блокировался и при начатом `Anti-AFK`, игрок тоже мог управлять персонажем. Но когда я включаю `Anti-AFK`, персонаж бегает по квадрату, но если попытаться им управлять, ничего не выходит, либо осуществить действие (к примеру нажатие пробела). Персонаж зависает и продолжает бегать вприпрыжку. Скажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?

```
import pyautogui
import pydirectinput # тоже библиотека для управления клавиатурой и мышью.
from pynput import keyboard


class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.collect_events()

    def collect_events(self):
        with keyboard.Listener(on_release=self.check_pressed_button) as k_listener:
            k_listener.join()

    def check_pressed_button(self, key):
        if key == keyboard.Key.f7:
            print('Anti-AFK is starting')
            for global_repeat in range(12):
                for local_repeat in range(4):
                    pydirectinput.keyDown('w')
                    pyautogui.moveRel(-782, 0)
            pydirectinput.keyUp('w')
            print('Anti-AFK is ending')


obj = Main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обязателен ли именно такой алгоритм работы как у вас? Мне удалось решить проблему путем использования библиотеки `keyboard` *(pip install keyboard)* и [Документация](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/).

В цикле **`while True`** идет точно такое же ожидание нажатия клавиши *F7*, после нажатия запускается алгоритм и работает без указанных вами проблем. После выполнения, в цикле снова ожидается нажатие *F7*

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard

while True:
    keyboard.wait('f7')
    print('Anti-AFK is starting')
    for global_repeat in range(12):
        for local_repeat in range(4):
            pyautogui.keyDown('w')
            pyautogui.moveRel(-782, 0)
    pydirectinput.keyUp('w')
    print('Anti-AFK is ending')
```

Что касается мышки, здесь ситуация другая. Мышка также контролируется библиотекой, но при попытке ее использования, такого ощущения контроля со стороны пользователя, как с клавиатурой, не будет. Самое простое, что можно сделать - реализовать бег по квадрату полностью через клавиатуру, то есть клавиши "WASD".